# I am getting error for email connection setting in Sitecore

Tags: exm

I've changed the SMTP setting in `Sitecore.EDS.Providers.CustomSMTP.config`, Is any other thing to change for the *Email Experience Manager(EXM)* connection.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you change in web.config to use a custom smtp ?

Comment: you need to have <add key="eds:define" value="CustomSmtp" />

Comment: @VladIobagiu i defined both above

Comment: In sitecore.config file i defined the same settings and its working file but not with EXM

Comment: there is a typo in your host smpt instead of smtp

Comment: OMG, Thanks @AbhayDhar ,you are incridable!

Comment: is that a sarcastic comment ?

Comment: No,You saved my time, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

As I know **GMail** works only with *secure connection*, please try these settings:

```
<smtpSettings type="Sitecore.EDS.Core.Net.Smtp.SmtpSettings, Sitecore.EDS.Core" singleInstance="true">
    <server>smtp.gmail.com</server>
    <port>587</port>
    <userName>you_login@gmail.com</userName>
    <password>your_password</password>
    <authenticationMethod>LOGIN</authenticationMethod>
    <startTls>true</startTls>
    <proxySettings ref="exm/eds/proxySettings" />
</smtpSettings>
```